# Is there ways to "go back" on a PostBack?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got stumped here in this,

I have a form that the user fills out with varius info and then i postback this to another page where they can check their input and added info from the system, if there is something wrong i have a "back" button and i want to "postback" the same info back to the first page again. Tried this and the circular police of YMCA stopped me in a second and gave me a warning. :/

The first postback works great, no trubbles so i just thought i use the same way to go back...but no.

Am i just doing this the wrong way or just the wrong how to? I thought crossposting was the way to move alot of variables between pages.

i have been using the msdn way described [cross posting msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

/Thanks

Comment: Did you consider cookies?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you performing a postback to another page? Typically in asp.net a postback is to the same page. If you are requiring passing data between pages I would construct a workflow where you store the information required in a database and then keep an identifier for that information in the session for that user. And recall it on pages you need it on. Or just keep the information you need in the session. However this is not really recommended for a few reasons depending on the data.

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell I'm trying to pass the form to another page that presents it in another layout and if the user wants to edit again I need the values back into the first page again for edit. Database is an option but I got my head stuck into this one and I want to see if there are any nice ways out aswell.

Comment: Don't bother with the other page, if it is a postback just change what you render. It will solve you several problems and take much less time. Have a panel for entering values, and a panel for showing values. On click of a button for editing, postback again. if there is a no postback render the input panel, if there is a postback and your event target is the postback for edit, then show the input panel, otherwise if there is a postback show the preview panel. Or always render the input panel and just have a preview pane. Those are my suggestions.